# Time-series data in QGIS point layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I work in a project in QGIS where I have some layers with points. All these points are stations. For each station I have a table in database with time-series measurements. 
**I want to find a way to click on each point and have some type of menu from where I can plot a graph based on stored measurements I have in database**.
Is there any plugin that can help me with this functionality?

Comment: I also in a need of a similar solution and I am trying to explore DataPlotly to figure out of its done. Please share any useful tutorials on how to use multiple layer data in DataPlotly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the [DataPlotly](https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly) plugin would be the right thing for you. Note the actual name is "Data Plotly" in the QGIS plugin manager.

Note that you have to convert date fields to string to use them with Dataplotly. There is a known issue, with workaround. See [github issue](https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/issues/122)